# Get SQLCODE and SQLSTATE from stored procedure with executing a statement from variable

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, db2, execute

I have this:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE log_test
                                 ( IN QUERY VARCHAR(24576),
                                   IN LOGTBL varchar(20) ) LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE v_select_query VARCHAR(24576);
DECLARE v_query VARCHAR(24576);
DECLARE v_logtbl varchar(20);
DECLARE v_errormsg varchar(2048);
DECLARE v_time TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE v_temp_select varchar(1024);
DECLARE stmt STATEMENT;
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
FOR SQLEXCEPTION,SQLWARNING,NOT FOUND
    SET v_sqlcode = SQLCODE;




set v_select_query  = 'Set (?) = ('||QUERY||')';
set v_query  = 'Set (?) = ('||QUERY||')';
set v_bezug  = bezug;
set v_logtbl = logtbl;
set v_time   = CURRENT TIMESTAMP;



PREPARE stmt from v_select_query;

EXECUTE stmt into v_temp_select;

END @
```

The statement query is

```
 select count(*) from testtbl;
```

and without the sqlstate catching it works.

The result is that I want the sqlcode saved in the variables when the statement is successful or fails. However now I only get an error message that after "" the unexpected token "".

Any ideas on how to fix this? I later want to log the sqlcode with an insert into another table.

DB2 Windows v10.5

Thanks for your help

Comment: If an SQL statement succeeds, SQLCODE is always zero.  If an SQL statement fails, SQLCODE is not zero and SQLSTATE is set to something different than '00000'.  As you have declared an EXIT HANDLER that simply sets a local variable then on SQL statement failure your sproc will exit immediately , meaning your exit handler as currently coded is useless although you can extend it to insert the sqlcode/sqlstate into another table (better to call an autonomous sproc for that purpose to ensure a separate UOW).

Comment: Also you cannot have *both* a continue and an exit-handler for SQLEXCEPTION. You can have *one* of these.

Comment: I deleted the exit handler. How can I get the procedure to work? It does not compile

Comment: Fix the syntax errors, there are several obvious ones.  Put SQLCODE and SQLSTATE declarations first (before the statement declaration). Define the variables that are undefined (v_sqlcode, v_bezug etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, fix the syntax errors in your code. The example below will compile for Db2-LUW, but there are other errors and problems in your code that you will find later with testing.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE log_test
( IN QUERY VARCHAR(24576),
  IN LOGTBL varchar(20) ) 
LANGUAGE SQL
specific log_test
BEGIN
    DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE v_select_query VARCHAR(24576);
    DECLARE v_query VARCHAR(24576);
    DECLARE v_logtbl varchar(20);
    DECLARE v_errormsg varchar(2048);
    DECLARE v_time TIMESTAMP;
    DECLARE v_temp_select varchar(1024);
    DECLARE v_sqlcode INTEGER;
    DECLARE v_sqlstate CHAR(5);
    DECLARE v_bezug varchar(1024);

    DECLARE stmt STATEMENT;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING,NOT FOUND
        SET v_sqlcode = SQLCODE;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
        SET v_sqlstate = SQLSTATE;


    set v_select_query  = 'Set (?) = ('||QUERY||')';
    set v_query  = 'Set (?) = ('||QUERY||')';
    set v_bezug  = 'bezug';
    set v_logtbl = logtbl;
    set v_time   = CURRENT TIMESTAMP;



    PREPARE stmt from v_select_query;

    EXECUTE stmt into v_temp_select;

END@
```